# Summernote cannot set value get from database

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, summernote

i am fetching problem on summernote which is set the value on it. I can set the previous value on it, but cannot set the value get from database.

```
  @if (old('review_body') != "")
      var review_body = '<?php echo($review_body);?>';
      $('#summernote').summernote('code', review_body);
   @else
      var db_review_body = '<?php echo($db_review_body);?>';
      $(".summernote").summernote('code', db_review_body);
   @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `{!! $review_body !!}` instead of `<?php echo($review_body);?>` then you will get the exact thing from your database.